# how to use notepad++ for indenting ant file

Tags: ant, notepad++

I am using Notepad++ for writing my ant scripts.

However having some problem with the indentation. Tried to use the TextFX and then to use the HTML Tidy.

Have not worked out well as HTML Tidy adds html related stuffs.

Are there any other plugin that I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed the *[XML Tools plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/XML%20Tools/)* for Notepad++.

Then used the "Plugins --> XML Tools --> Pretty print (XML only - with line breaks)" and that solved my  formatting problem.